# Data Changed After set Adapter to Spinner

Tags: android

My data always gets size '1' after set to Spinner Adapter. I used `SearchableSpinner` to show data.

```
final SearchableSpinner spinnerProvince = selectLocation8v.getSpinnerProvince();

final ArrayList<String> arrayProvince = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<String> arrayKota = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<String> arrayKecamatan = new ArrayList<>();

final ArrayList<State> listProvinsi = lisaDbHelper.getStates();

for (int p = 0; p < listProvinsi.size(); p++) {
    arrayProvince.add(listProvinsi.get(p).getName());
}
ArrayAdapter provinceAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayProvince);
provinceAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinnerProvince.setAdapter(provinceAdapter);

System.out.println("Data count before set to adapter : " + provinceAdapter.getCount()); // 34

System.out.println("Data count after set to adapter  : " + spinnerProvince.getAdapter().getCount()); // 1
```

Comment: share your all code!

Comment: check my updated @HemantParmar

Comment: edit your code and write spinnerProvince.getAdapter().getCount()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many items are bound to spinner, you should call:

```
spinnerProvince.getAdapter().getCount()
```

Comment: i did, on `spinnerProvince.getAdapter().getCount()` i got 1 size but on `provinceAdapter.getCount()` i got 34 size data @godot

Answer (score 0):

in your log you trying to get number of item in spinner by  `spinnerProvince.getCount()` but this will not return actual value.

replace this code

```
System.out.println("Data count after set to adapter  : " + spinnerProvince.getCount());
```

To

```
System.out.println("Data count after set to adapter  : " + spinnerProvince.getAdapter().getCount());
```

i got the reference from [here](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/blob/master/searchablespinnerlibrary/src/main/java/com/toptoche/searchablespinnerlibrary/SearchableSpinner.java) and i found that there no such method for returning spinner item count.

try to do that

```
Adapter adapter= (Adapterspinner )listProvinsi.getadapter();
int count = adapter.getCount();
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: `final SearchableSpinner spinnerProvince = selectLocation8v.getSpinnerProvince();` how much items it returning??

Comment: that code for call object SearchableSpinner like `spinnerProvince = findViewbyId(...)`

Comment: i update the code have look that and let me know that its working or not!

Comment: sorry sir, i mean after Array Data `provinceArray` set to adapter `spinnerProvince.setAdapter(provinceArray` and then when i check data count `spinnerProvince.getAdapter.getCount` is 1.